# Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery+TooManyClauses: System error

Tags: asp.net, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to search with the below params, and I am wondering why some cause this exception to be thrown.

Only a few params are not working.  All others are working.

- `?q=220v+0+ph` => Not working
- `?q=220v+1+ph` => Not working
- `?q=220v+2+ph` => Not working
- `?q=220v+3+ph` => Not working
- `?q=220v+4+ph` => Working
- `?q=220v+5+ph` => Working
- `?q=220v+6+ph` => Working
- `?q=220v+7+ph` => Working
- `?q=220v+8+ph` => Working
- `?q=220v+9+ph` => Working

I am checking the center character.  It is not working only in the cases of 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Query: `{+(title:480v* content:480v title:3* content:3 title:ph* content:ph)`

Answer (score 1):

One or more of your wildcard queries is generating too many term matches.  Wildcard queries are rewritten by enumerating all of the matching terms, and create a set of primitive queries matching them, combined in a `BooleanQuery`.

For instance, the query `title:foo*`, could be rewritten to `title:foobar title:food title:foolish title:footpad`, in an index containing those terms.

By default, a `BooleanQuery` allows a maximum of 1024 clauses.  If you have over 1024 *different terms* in the index matching `title:0*`, for instance, that is likely your problem.